# Error Handling while calling dynamic methods C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application with main method as follows:

```
public static void Main(string[] commandString)
{
    try
    {
        var asm = Assembly.Load("CAT");
        var t = asm.GetType("CAT",true,true);
        var _Adjudication = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
        t.InvokeMember("NAMEME", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, _Adjudication, new object[] { "Fluffy", 5});
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Environment.Exit(99);
    }
}
```

CAT class is as below :

```
public class CAT
{
    public void NAMEME(string name, int age)
    {
       try
       {
           throw new Exception();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }
    }
}
```

I have an error stating "Exception was unhandled by user code" when I run this program. The error is caught by the Catch block of the NAMEME method.

How do I get the exception to hit the catch block of my Main method?

PS : I am using .NET Framework 4.0
PPS: I was able to handle it by capturing the TargetInvocationException error

Comment: I can't reproduce. It works for me

Comment: You should use throw instead of throw ex

Comment: Of course it will catch in the NAMEME method first.  It will then throw and be caught in the Main method.  Continue to step through your code using F10.

Comment: i got the same problem for dynamic class, can anyone tell me the problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816233/c-sharp-user-defined-exception-handling-for-erroe-from-dll-get-exception-was-unh?noredirect=1#comment65000685_38816233

Answer (score 2):

This actually works, I copied all the source code and I have it running locally just fine. There are a few typoes in your code provided, but I assume they do not exist in your actual source on your dev box as you said you get the exception to hit in the `CAT` class. In order for it to hit the next `catch` in the main app, you need to continue once the exception is thrown -- it will then land where you'd expect it to.

[image]

Comment: Yep, same here, can't repro

Comment: In debug mode, I can 'continue' it. But when I run the exe via command line parameters, it wont 'continue' to exit with the error code of 99.

Comment: Then you must have not given us the full story or something is missing. I literally copied and pasted your code (minus the typo) and then stepped through it as expected.

Comment: Okay, I had to get rid of all the actual code in my CAT class as it's work-related.. But the scenario is the same. I invoke a method that throws an exception. File not found / IO .. whatever. The catch block in the CAT class captures it. But Main doesn't get to catch it

Comment: Try the code as you posted it: it works as you'd expect (both to me and to @DavidPine , at least), so there's something in what you have "got rid of" that is making it not work, and we can't guess it.